# Consuming a RESTfull webservice in Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: c#, web-services, botframework, restful-url

I am trying to call a restful API in my Bot application , the same code is working when I tested in a web application and a result in string type is returned in response.
I have used Web-Client and an UploadString() to fetch the result:

```
public virtual async Task GetOrderDetailforUser(IDialogContext context, 
IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{
    var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
    client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.ContentType, "application/json");            
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic <authentication-encoded>");
    var remoteResponse = client.UploadString(new Uri(stringURL), "POST", serializedData);
    var desearilaizeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<rootObjOutput>(remoteResponse);
}
```

while debugging, in remoteResponse, I get an exception as below:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
>      at System.Net.WebClient.UploadDataInternal(Uri address, String method, Byte[] data, WebRequest& request)
>      at System.Net.WebClient.UploadString(Uri address, String method, String data)
>      at MyBotApp.StateDialogTest.d__15.MoveNext() in..

Comment: Error 500 means something went wrong on the remote server and not in the bot. Maybe you should take a look at the data the API receives.

Comment: @Xeno-D , yes I looked around, but I am surprised that exactly same code is running alright in an aspx.cs (code behind) page of a website application in local host.  Does this mean that calling api through webclient is not supported in bot framework apps?

Comment: It is supported. I've used it a lot. Why are you using `UploadString` instead of `PostAsync`?

Comment: @Xeno-D, are you talking about HTTPClient's PostAsync?  I was using WebClient as this involves less coding. Can try PostAsync.

Comment: Yeah I always use HTTPClient so I forgot about the webclient. And it doesn't require that much more code. Give it a go and see if it works better. HTTPClient is generally better for making asynchronous calls.

Comment: HTTPClient worked!! Thanks! only difference is I used PostAsJsonAsync<my_InputObject_for_JSON>. So if the WebClient() does not work in bot that reason should be with asynchronous calls happening in chatbot. Yes this makes sense, as any in Bot Frameworks uses async methods.